# How to render more JSF components by using a ui:repeat component?

Tags: java, jsf

I have a question concerning the jsf component . Here is a small code example:

```
<ui:repeat var="bean" value="myBean.myListToIterate">
    <h:selectOneCheckbox value="#{myBean.specificField}" />
    #{bean.car.name} 
</ui:repeat>
```

**Question 1:** Why the expression `#{bean.car.name}` alone inside the `ui:repeat` element and why not for example in a

`<h:outputLabel value="#{bean.car.name}" />`"?

If i use this, nothing will be displayed.

**Question 2:** Why does this example doesn´t look very well, if i use a

`<h:selectOneRadio value="#{myBean.specificField}"/>` component

instead of a

`<h:selectOneCheckbox value="#{myBean.specificField}"/>` component?

Greetz
Marwief

Answer (score 0):

**Answer 1 :**
EL JSF expressions are allowed in the last JSF versions. So it can be put without any wrapping tag (like `<h:outputText />`).
Using this `<h:outputLabel value="#{bean.car.name}" />` did not give result, because you did not specify `for` attribute to point to, in order to be rendered as  `label` of its client id, which means, it cannot be used alone.

**Answer 2 :**
First, this JSF tag `<h:selectOneCheckbox />` doesn't exist, maybe you wanted to mean `<h:selectBooleanCheckbox />`. Replacing this by `<h:selectOneRadio ... />` does not look very well, because this last one needs `<f:selectItem />` or `<f:selectItems />` to hold choices from where the end user will be able to choose between (i.e at least 2 choices), in the contrary of `<h:selectBooleanCheckbox />` which can have no child select item(s) tag(s) in the case of one alone choice to (un)check.